# Going through list of objects and adding one of each value to another list in R

Tags: r

Here's a situation: 
I have a data from nycflights13 package, and I need to iterate through a column named 'carriers' and save them in a list but with no repetitions - every of them should appear in my list only once. Values of that column are 3-letters long strings.  For now I've produced this code:

```
carriers = list()

carriers_fun <- function(x,y)
{
   for ( i in x )
{
       if ( is.element(i,x) == FALSE )
{
           y = c ( y,i )
           return (y)
}
       else
{
           next
}}}
carriers_fun(data$carrier,carriers)
```

Where x is column which I have to go through and y is list in which strings are supposed to appear. Unfortunately my code returns an empty list. Why?

Comment: Isn't this the same thing as `unique(data$carrier)` ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted, much thanks for this solution.